# Opposing uniform pressures/forces

Tags: forces, pressure, stress-strain

If I have a vertical plate, with a uniform pressure of $10\,\text N/\text m^2$ acting on the left hand side, and a uniform pressure of $6\,\text N/\text m^2$ acting on the right hand side, can I treat it as if there is only a uniform pressure of $4\,\text N/\text m^2$ acting on the left hand side?

For the purpose of simple stress calculations.

Comment: Well, what do you think, and why?

Comment: I believe so. The reason behind this thought process was if there were equal uniform pressures applied on either side, you would expect it to be in a state of equilibrium in terms of bending, eg. No bending stresses. However as there is an additional pressure of 4N/m2 acting on the left, I would expect to see bending stress relative to that force load per unit area. Resulting in the right hand side being in tension, and left hand side under compression.

Comment: To have bending stress there needs  to be restraints on the vertical plate that you haven’t described

Comment: It is clamped at both ends so treating it as fixed.